# How to get nav links(buttons) in header next to image

Tags: css, button, header, nav

I have my nav inside the header. I have an image in the corner and want the navigation links, which I made as buttons, on the right, but higher up within the white box. I had a problem with the header not resizing when i shrunk the page but I fixed that, but now the buttons are off the header. They also do not resize when I shrink the page. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks. The url is http://tolitakeover.com

Here is html:

```
<header>
    <nav> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="contact.html" class="button">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="button">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html" class="button">TBD</a></li>               
            <li><a href="affiliates.html" class="button">Affiliates</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html" class="button">Events</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Here is css:

```
nav{
   background:url('http://tolitakeover.com/images/toliheader.fw.png');
   background-size: 40% 100%;
   margin-left: 5%;
   width: 90%;
   height: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   background-color:white;
}

nav ul{
   padding-top:20%;
   padding-right:3%;
   height:60%;
}

nav li{
    display:inline;
   float:right;
   padding-right:1%;
   padding-top:-50px;
}

nav ul li a,
   nav ul li a:visited{
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
   display:block;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
   text-decoration:none;
   background-color:white;
   color:black;
}

.button {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: black;
   font-weight: bold;
   background-color: lightgray;
   padding: 5px 20px;
   margin-left:3%;
   margin-right:3%;
   font-size: 1.15em;
   border: 1px solid red;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px lightgray, 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4), inset 0px 1px 0px       rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px lightgray, 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px lightgray, 0px 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.4), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.5);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot going on.

Question, where did you get this stylesheet from? It is bad news for what you're trying to do. I wouldn't even know where to begin to explain this...

I recommend you start from scratch w/ a nice clean responsive template such as this:

http://www.initializr.com/

When you say 're-size' page do you mean when it degrades to mobile or tablet? You have no rules for this in your CSS.

Also, looking at your CSS I recommend you give this a read: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: I totally understand, did you see my follow-up?

Comment: i only provided that part of the css.. the css for resizing to mobile or tablet i have at the bottom of the page... when i say resize the page i meant when you drag the webpage in and make it smaller i want it to make the buttons smaller but they were getting distored.. and all that mess of css came from trying to figure out how to get what i wanted i know most of that should be done more easily

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to go that route, you would use "clearfix" instead, clearing the nav class from the header?

He should ideally have three classes up there, something like: #menu #container clearfix #navigation This would allow him to also control his logo too, as right now it's in the #nav.